# Rails Form Example

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I'm new to forms in Rails so this may be a very basic question.

I have an HTML page that I would like to turn into a basic form:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>What is your age?</h2>
            <input type="number" id="age"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>What is your zip code?</h2>
            <input type="number" id="zip"><br>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>What is your gender?</h2>
            <select id="gender">
                <option></option>
                <option value="42198">Male</option>
                <option value="42199">Female</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>Are you of Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin?</h2>
            <select id="hispanic">
                <option></option>
                <option value="42200">No , not of Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin</option>
                <option value="42201">Yes, Mexican, Mexican American, Chicano</option>
                <option value="42202">Yes, Cuban</option>
                <option value="42203">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Argentina</option>
                <option value="42204">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Colombia</option>
                <option value="42205">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Ecuador</option>
                <option value="42206">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** El Salvadore</option>
                <option value="42207">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Guatemala</option>
                <option value="42208">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Nicaragua</option>
                <option value="42209">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Panama</option>
                <option value="42210">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Peru</option>
                <option value="42211">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Spain</option>
                <option value="42212">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Venezuela</option>
                <option value="42213">Yes, another Hispanic, Latino, or Spanish origin *** Other Country</option>
                <option value="42214">Prefer not to answer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>What is your race?</h2>
            <select id="ethnicity">
                <option></option>
                <option value="42215">White</option>
                <option value="42216">Black, or African American</option>
                <option value="42217">American Indian or Alaska Native</option>
                <option value="42218">Asian *** Asian Indian</option>
                <option value="42219">Asian *** Chinese</option>
                <option value="42220">Asian *** Filipino</option>
                <option value="42221">Asian *** Japanese</option>
                <option value="42222">Asian *** Korean</option>
                <option value="42223">Asian *** Vietnamese</option>
                <option value="42224">Asian *** Other</option>
                <option value="42225">Pacific Islander *** Native Hawaiian</option>
                <option value="42226">Pacific Islander *** Guamanian</option>
                <option value="42227">Pacific Islander *** Samoan</option>
                <option value="42228">Pacific Islander *** Other Pacific Islander</option>
                <option value="42229">Some other race</option>
                <option value="42230">Prefer not to answer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>What is your relationship status?</h2>
            <select id="standard_relationship">
                <option></option>
                <option value="42231">Single, never married</option>
                <option value="42232">Married</option>
                <option value="42233">Separated, divorced or widowed</option>
                <option value="42234">Domestic partnership/living with someone</option>
                <option value="42235">Prefer not to answer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <h2>What is the highest level of education you have completed?</h2>
            <select id="standard_education">
                <option></option>
                <option value="42236">3rd Grade or less</option>
                <option value="42237">Middle School - Grades 4 - 8</option>
                <option value="42238">Completed some high school</option>
                <option value="42239">High school graduate</option>
                <option value="42240">Other post high school vocational training</option>
                <option value="42241">Completed some college, but no degree</option>
                <option value="42242">Associate Degree</option>
                <option value="42243">College Degree (such as B.A., B.S.)</option>
                <option value="42244">Completed some graduate, but no degree</option>
                <option value="42245">Masters degree</option>
                <option value="42246">Doctorate degree</option>
                <option value="42247">None of the above</option>
            </select>
            <h2>How much total combined income do all members of your household earn before taxes?</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <select id="standard_hhi_us">
                <option></option>
                <option value="43490">Less than $5,000</option>
                <option value="43491">$5,000 to $9,999</option>
                <option value="43492">$10,000 to $14,999</option>
                <option value="43493">$15,000 to $19,999</option>
                <option value="43494">$20,000 to $24,999</option>
                <option value="43495">$25,000 to $29,999</option>
                <option value="43496">$30,000 to $34,999</option>
                <option value="43497">$35,000 to $39,999</option>
                <option value="43498">$40,000 to $44,999</option>
                <option value="43499">$45,000 to $49,999</option>
                <option value="43500">$50,000 to $54,999</option>
                <option value="43501">$55,000 to $59,999</option>
                <option value="43502">$60,000 to $64,999</option>
                <option value="43503">$65,000 to $69,999</option>
                <option value="43504">$70,000 to $74,999</option>
                <option value="43505">$75,000 to $79,999</option>
                <option value="43506">$80,000 to $84,999</option>
                <option value="43507">$85,000 to $89,999</option>
                <option value="43508">$90,000 to $94,999</option>
                <option value="43509">$95,000 to $99,999</option>
                <option value="43510">$100,000 to $124,999</option>
                <option value="43511">$125,000 to $149,999</option>
                <option value="43512">$150,000 to $174,999</option>
                <option value="43513">$175,000 to $199,999</option>
                <option value="43514">$200,000 to $249,999</option>
                <option value="43515">$250,000 and above</option>
                <option value="43516">Prefer not to answer</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Basically on clicking the `<input type="submit">` button, I would like to make a `POST` to my

`example#post_action`

In that call I would like to pass in the values of all of my fields.

So the `#age` numeric value, and the values of the selected dropdown, so `#gender` might have a value of `42198` if Male is selected, etc.

What's the most appropriate way to define this type of a form in Rails? Giving that this isn't for a specific user, I can't really do a `form_for` call here, as these values will not be stored directly in columns.

EDIT:

Attempting to use a `form_tag` here, I get this response which is missing the inputs/dropdowns that are filled out:

```
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WW9mpi6cdJhlR5nvUFGh95K1PKq1YyexC+SV14+0IAuAd5ZFTqAiOlD1+zFbT2X5RP5uiPiFQlT0VjG9PrOE4g==", "commit"=>"Save"}
{"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"WW9mpi6cdJhlR5nvUFGh95K1PKq1YyexC+SV14+0IAuAd5ZFTqAiOlD1+zFbT2X5RP5uiPiFQlT0VjG9PrOE4g==", "commit"=>"Save", "controller"=>"routers", "action"=>"pulley_post"}
```

Updated code:

```
<%= form_tag('/routers/pulley_post') do -%>
    #above html code
    <div><%= submit_tag 'Save' %></div>
<% end -%>
```

Comment: To supplement the answers you have which should give you a good start you might want to reference [Form Helpers](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use `form_for` and use a helper method somewhere on `application_helper.rb` or other helper module to pass options for f.select

form template:

```
<%= form_for @user, :url => { :action => "create" } do |f| %>
  <label>age</label>
  <%= f.text_field :age %>
  <label>gender</label>
  <%= f.select :gender, options_for_select(gender_options), { prompt: 'Select gender' } %>
  <label>ethnicity</label>
  <%= f.select :ethnicity, options_for_select(ethnicity_options), { prompt: 'Select ethnicity' } %>
  <%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

helper methods for passing options into form's select field (application_helper.rb):

```
def gender_options
  [ ["male", '42198'], ["female", '42199'] ]
end

def ethnicity_options
  [ ["No, not of Hispanic, Latino or Spanish", '42200'], ["Yes, Mexican, Mexican American", '42201'] ]
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Besides `form_for` there is also [`form_tag`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.4/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormTagHelper.html#method-i-form_tag) for non-resourceful forms (forms that are not coupled to a Rails model).

Comment: So that seems to get me a call, but it doesn't seem to include any of the inputs/dropdowns. I updated my code and response.